# CardMedia inside Materil UI is showing on the left side

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

CardMedia inside Grid shows as left postioned even after adding `justifyContent` and `alignItems` to center.

```
  <main className={classes.content}>
    <div className={classes.toolbar} />
    <Grid container spacing={0} alignItems="center" justify="center">
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
          <CardMedia
            className={classes.card}
            component="img"
            media="picture"
            alt="Contemplative Reptile"
            height="140"
            src={spot}
            title="Contemplative Reptile"
          />
      </Grid>
      <Grid item xs={12} sm={6}>
        <Typography paragraph className={classes.aboutText} align="center">
          <p>Hello World !!!</p>
          <p> I'm Lakshmipriya </p>
          Senior Software Engineer using javascript as main working tool,
          both in front-end and backend. Intrested in learning and building
          usefull web particles.
        </Typography>
      </Grid>
    </Grid>
  </main>
```

[CodesandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-4dnsh?file=/demo.js:4883-5852&resolutionWidth=1400&resolutionHeight=800)

Answer (score 0):

TLDR;

Try the following:

```html
<Grid item xs={12} sm={6} md={4} lg={3}>
```

**Explanation:**

You have 2 grid items inside the grid container. Both of them have `xs={12} sm={6}` - which means that the items will take 12 (fullwidth) for xs devices or larger and 6 (half-width) for sm devices for larger.

They both are taking up 50% width, which leaves 0 space for aligning and justifying.

You can add other breakpoints like - `lg={4}` and then they will be centre aligned and justified.